# How to make Android list item pass id on to next view?

Tags: java, android, argument-passing

In my (first) Android App I have a list of items. Each item is displayed using item.xml in which I have a RelativeLayout. In this layout I defined `android:onClick="showItemDetails"` of which the method looks like this:

```
public void showItemDetails(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, itemDetails.class);
    intent.putExtra("itemId", "5");
    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

As you can see I pass on a hardcoded id, so whatever item you currently click on, it obviously only shows item nr 5. I now need to dynamically give this method the id. The itemlist is created in the ItemListAdapter class of which a part is this:

```
holder.description.setText(rowItem.eventDescription);
holder.amount.setText(rowItem.getDisplayAmount());
```

I also have the id under `rowItem.id`, but I'm kinda lost on what I should do with it.

Can anybody help me out a bit here? What do I need to do to have the list items correctly pass the id through to the itemDetails class? All tips are welcome!

Comment: do not use `android:onClick`(`View.OnClickListener` implementation) ...  use `ListView/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` implementation instead + override `getItemId` of adapter and return `rowItemsss.get(position).id` then in `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick(...)` implementation you will get your id in `id` arg

Comment: @Selvin: this is an answer, not a comment

Comment: @gunar as you can see, writing good answer takes a time :)

Comment: @kramer65 check "or:" code in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First few assumptions:

- you're not using `Fragments` just plain `Activity` called `OuterActivityClass`
- `rowItem` var has typ `RowItemClass`
- your `ItemListAdapter` is extending `ArrayAdapter<RowItemClass>`
- you do it "right" (`ItemListAdapter` do not have own `List<RowItemClass>` field, `rowItem` in `getView(...)` is assigned like `rowItem = getItem(possition);` not like `rowItem = yourListFieldInAdapter.get(position);`(I do not know why Ppls using such field since`ArrayAdapter<?>` already has it internally) ... if you do it "bad" replace all `getItem(possition)` occurrence in my answer with `yourListFieldInAdapter.get(position)`
- id field of `RowItemClass` is long or int (if not use "or:" version)

What you have to do:

1. get rid of `android:onClick` from `item.xml`
2. override `hasStableIds()` in `ItemListAdapter`: `public boolean hasStableIds () { return true; }`
3. override `getItemId(...)` in adapter: `public long getItemId (int position) { return getItem(position).id; }`
4. in `Activity` `onCreate(...)` get ListView: `ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.your_listview_id);`
5. then assign the listener to your listView(in onCreate, too)

code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
      Intent intent = new Intent(OuterActivityClass.this, itemDetails.class);
      intent.putExtra("itemId", id + ""); //+ "" to make it string, of course you can use long but you have to remeber to use intent.getLongExtra(...) in details Activity
      startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```

or:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
      final RowItemClass clickedItem  = (RowItemClass)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
      Intent intent = new Intent(OuterActivityClass.this, itemDetails.class);
      intent.putExtra("itemId", clickedItem.id + "");
      startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```

with second method you can omit points 2. and 3. (if you are using "bad" way remeber to override `getItem` (`return yourListFieldInAdapter.get(pos)`) and `getCount`(
`return yourListFieldInAdapter.size()`)in your adapter implementation)

Offtopic hint: do not use lower case as first letter in class name `itemDetails` => `ItemDetails` ... for your sanity :) (OMG, OMG, itemDetails is variable or class name )

Comment: Awesome! I'm almost there! The only thing I don't get is what the OuterActivityClass should be?

Comment: you have class which extends Activity with `showAllOverviewEvents` ... you should replace OuterActivityClass with name of this class ... since `this` in anonymouse OnItemClickListener implementation is type of `OnItemClickListener` not outer class: `class Outer { class Inner { void Method() { /*here this means Inner instance but Outer.this means Outer instance */} } } `

Answer (score 0):

```
In your Main Activity

String item =  country.getName();
           Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivityActivity.this,AnotherActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_RESPONSE, item);
                    startActivity(intent);





In Next Activity
String country =  getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_COUNTRY);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPhone);
    textView.setText(country);
```

Answer (score -2):

If I understand correctly your problem then you might try to set OnClickListener in your adapter(don't set onClick in xml). And in your adapter try something like:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ...
     View rootLayout = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_layout_root);  
     ...
     rootLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
           showItemDetails(rowItem.id);  
         }
     });
return convertView;
```

And your showItemDetails will change to

```
showItemDetails(int id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, itemDetails.class);
    intent.putExtra("itemId", id);
    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: @Selvin - How would you suggest to do it then?